# How can I access a Graphical User Interface of a CentOS machine via my windows machine

Tags: linux, centos

So here's the down low:

I have someone hosting a CentOS 7 machine for me in a remote location. I can access this machine via SSH, currently using PuTTy, and that is all.

My knowledge on Linux coding is limited if it even exists at all.

What I am basically looking for is a step by step guide on how to setup a GUI for this CentOS box and then view this GUI on my windows machine to be able to perform tasks, installations etc etc on my hosted CentOS box.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers.

Comment: Are you sure that there is a graphical interface set up on the machine? I think the default server setup on Centos is to not have a graphical interface. Ask the one hosting the computer. Also ask then what is the graphical environment, X, Wayland or something else.

Answer (score 1):

CentOS comes in a slew of [variants.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20379/centos-6-default-installation-options) For most users, there two main options are the GUI installation. or the minimal installation.

1. Check if you have a working GUI environment installed.

If you had CentOS setup in minimal mode, it does not come with a GUI, only a console. Hence you will have to install it separately.

Here's a StackOverflow [article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181503/how-to-install-desktop-environments-on-centos-7) on a few desktops environment available on the CentOS platform and how install them.

2. Once you are certain you have a working GUI, you can employ a remote access application like [VNC](https://www.realvnc.com/download/viewer/windows/).

Here's a full [guide](http://www.linuxtechi.com/install-configure-vnc-server-centos-7-rhel-7/) on how get CentOS to display through VNC on a Windows machine.